# POP EMail with Alpine (Pine)

Tags: pop3, alpine-mail

Over the years I used Pine off and on, especially i college

How can I setup Pine to POP down my mail so it is local on my machine? I dont like storing my mail on a server someplace, I like to have it local so I can back it up,etc

Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 3):

From *[Configuring Alpine](http://www.mediusrete.org/progs/calpine.html)*:

> Start by going to the "Setup
>   Configuration" screen (M S C) and find
>   the Folder Preferences section. Under
>   this section, set
>   enable-incoming-folders and restart
>   alpine for the change to take effect.
>   Now go to your Incoming Message
>   Folders (F Incoming-Folders), but
>   don't open your INBOX folder.
>
> Now comes the fun part.
>
> Since you want to add a new folder,
>   type A. You'll be presented with a
>   command-line asking for the "Name of
>   server to contain added folder" and
>   four options below that. We're
>   interested in the options. Since
>   you're going to be pulling mail off of
>   a remote pop3 server, you want to
>   configure a mail drop, which is the
>   last option, thus press Ctrl W. You'll
>   now be asked for the name of the mail
>   drop server (the server you're pulling
>   the mail off of). Enter the server
>   (and port number if you desire), your
>   username (which may or may not include
>   part of the server address), and pop3.
>   When done, you should have something
>   that looks like the following:
>
> `pop.server.tld:port/user=username@server.tld/pop3`
>
> If you are using a secure connection,
>   you will need to add two things to the
>   entry. First, append ssl to the end.
>   When that is done (and assuming you
>   don't want, or are having difficulties
>   setting up, certificate validation),
>   add novalidate-cert just after the
>   mail drop server. Once you are done,
>   you should have something that
>   resembles the following:
>
> `pop.server.tld:port/novalidate-cert/user=username@server.tld/pop3/ssl`
>
> Now hit Enter. You'll now be asked for
>   the folder you want to copy the mail
>   from; answer: Inbox.
>
> Next: "Name of server to contain
>   destination folder". Leave this blank,
>   and continue on.
>
> Now for the "Folder to copy mail to".
>   You can name this anything you want,
>   but I generally use the user name of
>   whatever email account I'm setting the
>   mail drop up for.
>
> And I do the same as above for the
>   "Nickname for folder "username"".
>
> And now you have a brand new mail drop
>   folder. To set up more, just repeat as
>   needed.

*[Alpine e-mail setup](http://shakthimaan.com/installs/alpine-email-setup.html)* also has Alpine setup instructions, including how to set up Gmail using POP3 (including pictures):

> This is an example of using POP3 from
>   Gmail. You will need to enable POP3
>   from your Gmail account under
>   Settings→Forwarding and POP/IMAP.
>
> To create a new incoming folder for
>   POP, use Main Menu→Folder
>   List→Incoming-Folders→Add.
>
> It will prompt to ask you the Name of
>   server to contain added folder:
>
> `Name of server to contain added folder: pop.gmail.com:995/novalidate-cert/user=username@gmail.com/pop3/ssl`
>
> It will then prompt to ask for the
>   'Folder on 'pop.gmail.com…" to add:
>
> `Folder on "pop.gmail.com.." to add:
>    INBOX`
>
> Fill in a nickname:
>
> `Nickname for folder "INBOX" : INBOX at
>    gmail.com`
>
> It will then connect to
>   gmail server and will prompt for the
>   username@gmail.com password. Enter it,
>   and the INBOX will open.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the `.pinerc` file for editing.
2. Search for the `"incoming-folders="` option.
3. Add:

   ```
   nick_name "#move {server}inbox_folder local_mail_folder"
   ```
4. Save the updated version of .pinerc
5. Create an empty mail folder in your prefered location:

   ```
   touch local_mail_folder
   ```

Example:

Add:

```
incoming-folders=GMAIL "#move pop.gmail.com/ssl/user=user@gmail.com/novalidate-cert}INBOX /home/user/mail/gmail"
```

And next:

```
$ touch /home/user/mail/gmail
```

If you would like to define this for two or more accounts, separate them with ",".

Comment: Actually, `local_mail_folder` is a file.